# How to find synonyms between 2 word lists in python?

Tags: python, synonym

I have 2 word lists, I want to find (all words in word_list_2)'s synonyms  from word_list_1:

word_list_1:

```
 'right',
 'head',
 'left',
 'mass',
 'removal',
 'terminal',
 'carbon dioxide'
 'dominance'
 'initiation'
  ...
```

word_list_2:

```
'right',
'co2',
'control',
'creation',
'end',
 ...
```

Expected example is like:

```
synonym for right:   #right is from word_list_2
'right'    #right is from word_list_1

synonym for co2:   #co2 is from word_list_2
'carbon dioxide'   #carbon dioxide is from word_list_1

synonym for control:    #control is from word_list_2
'dominance'        #dominance is from word_list_1

synonym for creation:  #creation is from word_list_2
'initiation'      #initiation is from word_list_1
...
```

Find the synonyms between these 2 lists. How do I do this in python?Thanks!

(I tried to use wordnet, but the program failed, I guess it's because my 2 word lists contain multiple words instead of single word.)

```
word = word_list_2
sent = word_list_1

def get_word_synonyms_from_sent(word, sent):
    word_synonyms = []
    for i in word:
        for synset in wordnet.synsets(i):
            for lemma in synset.lemma_names():
                if lemma in sent and lemma != i:
                    word_synonyms.append(lemma)
    return word_synonyms

word_synonyms = get_word_synonyms_from_sent(word, sent)
print ("SYNONYMS FOR '" + word.upper() + "' FOUND IN THE SENTENCE: " + ", ".join(word_synonyms))
```

Comment: You are expected to show some effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The rules are confusing... Seems like your labels for which list a word is from are not quite right? E.g. `co2` is from list 2. Do you have some mapping for synonyms, or some list of meanings? What you're describing is basically impossible without some other data.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just make updates.

Comment: You must first have a table of some sort that indicates, for each word, which other words are synonyms for that.

Comment: The code you posted helps, but please show what error you're getting. And also how you import wordnet, this failed for me with `AttributeError: module 'wordnet' has no attribute 'synsets'`, which doesn't sound like the same result you're getting.

Comment: From the name "synset" I'm guessing it's a set of synonyms. I'm pretty sure you should be using set operations instead of looping over the set. Beyond that it's hard to speculate without some guidance on what wordnet and synset are. I'm guessing you should add the NLTK tag, and import them as joanis mentioned.